# Vault approle auth forces default policy

Tags: hashicorp-vault

When creating a role using Approle Auth method I do tell Vault to create the generated tokens under a a test policy

```
vault write auth/approle/role/test \
bind_secret_id=true \
secret_id_num_uses=0 \
token_num_uses=100 \
token_ttl=10m \
token_max_ttl=10m \
policies=test
```

I get the roleid and a secretid:
    vault read auth/approle/role/test/role-id
    vault write -f auth/approle/role/test/secret-id
And use it to generate a token:

```
vault write auth/approle/login \
role_id=a36f3615-9532-983a-991b-f5f4bff9723a \
secret_id=d74458b0-b076-12c6-fc5d-d5f92273ef9d
```

I get a generated token now inspect the generated token:

```
  vault token lookup ddfe8514-4a9a-c14b-9179-576db031a137                                                                
  Key                 Value
  ---                 -----
  accessor            b8aecbf5-e0d1-d016-1c02-3e1a1fd5098a
  creation_time       1532330714
  creation_ttl        600
  display_name        approle
  entity_id           bcd8a77a-85df-8224-e5ff-9390cae15e25
  expire_time         2018-07-23T09:35:14.579632638+02:00
  explicit_max_ttl    0
  id                  ddfe8514-4a9a-c14b-9179-576db031a137
  issue_time          2018-07-23T09:25:14.579632516+02:00
  meta                map[role_name:test]
  num_uses            100
  orphan              true
  path                auth/approle/login
  policies            [default test]
  renewable           true
  ttl                 580
```

And there it is! The default policy...
There is no documentation on how to skip default policy at Approle. Anyone have the same issue?

Comment: `token_no_default_policy=true`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the [official documentation](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/concepts/policies.html#default-policy):

> The default policy is a builtin Vault policy that cannot be removed.
>   By default, it is attached to all tokens, but may be explicitly
>   excluded at token creation time by supporting authentication methods.

**EDIT**

According to [this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vault-tool/kGWLjpam5Oc), it's not actually possible to remove the default policy from AppRole. As you said, this could be a feature to be [requested](https://github.com/hashicorp/vault/issues/5088) for future releases.

Comment: Same results:

     vault write auth/approle/login role_id=a36f3615-9532-983a-991b-f5f4bff9723a 
     secret_id=d74458b0-b076-12c6-fc5d-d5f92273ef9d policies=[test]
     Key                     Value
     token                   c0c86e20-0f33-0c4a-d38d-c683f6654417
     token_accessor          00503e9e-bcfe-6035-71dc-88651402ce6d
     token_duration          10m
     token_renewable         true
     token_policies          ["default" "test"]
     identity_policies       []
     policies                ["default" "test"]
     token_meta_role_name    test

Comment: Actually is not a huge problem for me and I can also edit the default policy to just dump it but I was wondering if there was someone that faced this problem too. 
I think I could raise a feature request to Hashicorp instead, this question is actually a first step before raise it.